# 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: apache, сервер

Есть скрипт на VPS, который выполняется раз в день. При выполнении ровно через 60 секунд выдает 504 Gateway Time-out
в htaccess прописано:
php_value max_execution_time 800
php_value max_input_time 800
php_value proxy_send_timeout 800
php_value proxy_read_timeout 800
php_value proxy_connect_timeout 750

и ничего не меняется, хоть phpini() и выдает верные значение
куда копать?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего Вы получаете ошибку 504 Gateway Time-out именно от сервера Apache, тогда можно попробовать поменять опцию Timeout, находится в файле конфигураций веб сервера, чаще всего это либо httpd.conf или httpd-default.conf. Найдите эти файлы и поменяйте этот параметр:

```
#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 60
```

Есть одно замечание по вашему алгоритму: такие скрипты не должны запускаться из HTTP интерфейса, а должны выполняться из командной строки, например по CRON. Ставить такие сумасшедшие значения для всех скриптов на сервере, это путь в никуда. Представьте, что у Вас что-то стало очень долго выполняться, и клиенты зашли на данный адрес, весь пул сервера может быть будет забит под нагрузкой, и новые клиенты просто не смогут зайти на ваш проект.

Comment: А если мне необходимо, чтобы timeout был больше только в одной папке, где выполняются скрипты. Файл будет запускаться один раз в сутки в 5 утра через cron

Comment: Если Вы будете запускать его через cron и командную строку, никаких ограничений Apache не будет применено, будут использоваться параметры из cli/php.ini и это лучший вариант. Если хотите и жаждите запускать через HTTP, то нужно например создавать отдельный виртуальный хост где будет указан бесконечный timeout :)

Answer (score 0):

Gateway time-out также может возникать, когда Nginx используется как прокси-сервер. Например, при работе с Apache. Для того, чтобы избежать проблем, необходимо настроить параметры времени ожидания при проксировании:

```
server {
    ...
    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
    proxy_send_timeout          600;
    proxy_read_timeout          600;
    send_timeout                600;
    ...
}
```